# Any way to never update an iOS device / not download the image?

Tags: ios

I have an iPod touch for development that I'm keeping on 4.3.  However, it has downloaded the seed for 6.0.  Is there anyway to tell it not to download 6.0 and to recover the memory that the seed is using?  It's a fairly substantial amount for an 8 gig device.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it has downloaded the seed? iOS 4.3 does not have an OTA update mechanism, so there's no way it could have downloaded the update.

I think it is possible to remove the OTA files, it they were downloaded, but only if the iOS device is jailbroken